# Unable to sign Windows exe and jars using javafx-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, javafx, build, inno-setup, code-signing

I am using the JavaFX Maven plugin in order to package my Java code into an `exe` and then subsequently use an installer to distribute my project using Inno Setup.

I am trying to sign the `jar`s, the `exe`, and the installer's `exe`. I am able to sign my installer's `exe` by using Windows sign tool after the `package` phase of the `javafx-maven-plugin` has built my installer.

However, I have not found any way to sign the `jar`s and the `exe` of the application. I have searched a lot and most searches points to resources that help you sign in the case of a web application. However, I have hit a dead end with respect to the native application on Windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: On OSX my application gets signed as it picks up a certificate from my keychain and signs everything.

Comment: This will help you: [Packaging Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABJGFBH) and this here too:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIADDAEE
You need to call the ant-tasks from maven with ant-run.

Comment: + to sign the .exe, use the signtool before compiling the installer, or use the `sign` flag. See http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool

Comment: Thanks for the links. The above method seems to be using ant to sign the jars. Is the javafx-maven-plugin not configured to perform this as my understanding is the plugin subsumes the ant tasks used in the javafx package management? Also the posts does not seem to indicate how to sign the native executable that is generated by the javafx-maven-plugin. Any thoughts regarding these?

Comment: Sorry Martin's post appeared only after I posted my reply. I will take a look at this by tweaking inno setup's property and see if I can get things to work like that.

Comment: I tried Martin's method in order to sign the components that are part of my installer along with the installer. However for the exe i am packaging i got an access denied error. Upon investigation i found that the readonly flag was set on the exe that was being packaged into the installer. Hence codesigning this component fails and stops my build process. I use the following signtool settings and i have set the sign flag on my files in the files section "<sigtool.exe path>" sign /f "<cert path>" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /p W5qbanZs6rQFDKkb $f. Thoughts?